# validate two forms with one submit button with jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two forms on one page with a starting and closing `<form></form>` tag for each form. I m validating it with JQuery Validate Plugin. I have to validate both forms with one single button. The problem is that validation of both forms required a separate button for each form which is not required. the code is given below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.formValidate').each(function() {   // <- selects every <form> on page
        $(this).validate({

    rules: {
         orderno: { //placed at first form
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },customername: { //placed at second form
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    },
    //For custom messages
    messages: {

        order:{
            required: "Enter a Order No",
            minlength: "Enter at least 5 characters"
        },customername:{
            required: "Enter a username",
            minlength: "Enter at least 5 characters"
        }

    },
    errorElement : 'div',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      var placement = $(element).data('error');
      if (placement) {
        $(placement).append(error)
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function() { 
        console.log("Order submitted!"); 
    }


 });
 });


}); //end readyfunction
```

HTML is as given below:-

```
<form class="formValidate" id="tstordform" method="get" action="">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="input-field col s12">
             <i class="mdi-image-tag-faces prefix"></i>
             <input  id="orderno" name="orderno" type="text" data-error=".errorTxt1">
             <label for="orderno">Order No.*</label>
             <div class="errorTxt1"></div>
          </div>
     </div>
</form>

<form class="formValidate" id="cstdataform" method="get" action="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="mdi-action-account-circle prefix"></i>
            <input id="customername" name="customername" type="text" data-error=".errorTxt6">
            <label for="customername">Customer Name</label>
            <div class="errorTxt6"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s3">
            <button id="validateboth" class="btn waves-effect waves-light center cyan submit" type="submit" name="action">Save Order
                <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Kindly help me!

Comment: Could you use this for your first line: `$(form).each(function() { `

Comment: if i use form tag then the page is reloaded and form is submitted. Both forms have different ids and same class.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that validation of both forms required a separate button for each form which is not required.

Not really sure what you mean, so showing your desired HTML markup would be helpful.

> I have to validate both forms with one single button.

Remove all buttons from both forms and put a single button outside of them.

Then write a handler that submits both forms at the same time.  This will trigger validation on both...

```
$('#submitboth').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('[id^="myform"]').submit();
});
```

DEMO 1:  [jsfiddle.net/293ps7k9/](http://jsfiddle.net/293ps7k9/)

The downside to this is that one or both forms will submit if/when there are no errors.

---

Alternatively, you can leave the submit buttons on each form and just create a third button and handler that triggers a validation test on both.

```
$('#validateboth').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('[id^="myform"]').each(function() {
        $(this).valid();  // <- validation test only
    });
});
```

DEMO 2:  [jsfiddle.net/tupn779c/](http://jsfiddle.net/tupn779c/)

---

**EDIT**:

> I have to first validate both forms and then submit the data of both forms via a single function call through ajax.

[Your single comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752902/validate-two-forms-with-one-submit-button-with-jquery-validate-plugin#comment70714401_41753369) explains it better than everything in your OP.  Although, **functionally, this is absolutely no different than putting everything inside of a single `form` container**.

The solution is practically the same as the two above:

1. Capture the `click` event of the single `submit` button contained *outside* of the `form` containers.  (Otherwise, you can use a `type="button"` and put it *anywhere* you want.)
2. Loop through the two forms looking for errors via the `.valid()` method.
3. Then when both forms pass validation, trigger a `.submit()` for both forms.  This will in turn trigger the `submitHandler` functions on each form where your Ajax is located.  (Ajax **must** go inside the `submitHandler` callback for each instance of `.validate()`)

See Final DEMO below.

```
$('#validateboth').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var forms = $('[id^="myform"]');
    forms.each(function() {
        $(this).valid();
    });
    if ($('#myform1').valid() && $('#myform2').valid()) {
        forms.submit();
    }
});
```

**Final DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/qtcs7uwe/](http://jsfiddle.net/qtcs7uwe/)

Comment: Its not working. if i use first solution then form is not validated and submitted.

Comment: I have to first validate both forms and then submit the data of both forms via a single function call through ajax. I have also added the html code above.

Comment: @user2782882, you simply have to tweak the methods I've already shown you.  See my third demo in the edited answer:  http://jsfiddle.net/qtcs7uwe/

Comment: Your solution is validating both forms but it does not show error on myform1. I.e. If i place input type button near first form then it shows error on first form and not on 2nd form. So it shows error on that form where i put the submit button.

Comment: @user2782882, did you make your button a `type="button"` as I instructed in my step #1?  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/qtcs7uwe/1/